# Joining within a table with ST_Intersects in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a table with the below structure:

| geom | name | ownership |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01031... | foo | landlord |
| 01032... | foo | landlord |
| 01033... | baz | landlord |
| 01034... | bar | tenant |
| 01035... | bar | tenant |
| 01036... | bar | tenant |

Landlords own a wide area and tenants own a small section within.

So, the geom of the tenant will at least intersect with the geom of the landlord.

I want to be able to search for a landlord by name, (`select * from table where name = 'foo' and ownership = 'landlord';`) and  get all of the geoms that the landlord owns and get the tenants with geoms inside those geoms.

Likewise, I want to search for a tenant, get all of the buildings they rent and find all of the enclosing landlord geoms.

Conceptually can't get my head around it. Is ST_Intersects the right method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `ST_Intersects` is the right message. You need to join a subset of the table (with the landlord of interest) to another subset (with the tenants), using `ST_Intersects`. Give the first subset the alias `l` and the second one the alias `t`.

```
SELECT t.name
FROM   table l 
JOIN   table t ON ST_Intersects(t.geom, l.geom)
WHERE  l.name = 'foo' AND l.ownership = 'landlord'
       AND t.ownership = 'tenant'
```

You might also want `ST_Within` or `ST_Contains` rather than `ST_Intersects`. [See the examples here](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html).

Comment: This syntax hasn't been used since ANSI 92 was released. Always use `JOIN` in anything released after Oracle 7

Comment: fair enough, updated the syntax.

Comment: "This syntax hasn't been used since ANSI 92 was released" citation needed, I see it all the time. I understand why people prefer explicit joins but being hyperbolic is unnecessary.